# Is there a way to display web component in the j2me program? I am programming for a s40 series Nokia phone

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, nokia, nokia-s40

I am trying to display a small web content in my application. Is there any way to display a web content?

Currently I am displaying a link, and upon clicking that link my application will close and web browser will open to display the web page?

I want to display the web content inside my application without closing my application.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMLComponent doesnot work upto mark and sometimes control swtching does'nt happen exactly according to flow but still we can use it as we dont have alternative solution in J2ME

Comment: my requirement is just to display a web content. There is no controls or any other actions performed using the web. As far as the content is visible, I am good. Will test this and update the results later.

Comment: if your just requirement is just to display webpage or webcomponent just use platformRequest and it doesnt closes your application and but if you need to display webpage inside (part of screen/form) then HTMLComponent is the only way

Answer (score 1):

[LWUIT](http://lwuit.java.net/) has a [HTMLcomponent](http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/iodocs/com/sun/lwuit/html/HTMLComponent.html) that you can use. It has limitations but can work

Comment: Thank you Gorkem Ercan, I will test this and update the results later.